# Which OOP concept describes how a Class alters or customises behaviours inherited from a parent Class?

Tags: oop

Am almost new to programming and i need your help to answer some multi-choice questions. Thanks

1. Which OOP concept describes how a Class alters or customises behaviours inherited from a parent Class? (Polymorphism or Inheritance)

Comment: Welcome to SO, Oludoyi Olumide! Stack Overflow is for asking questions about specific programming questions, not general coding questions for exams/homework. I'm afraid your question is off-topic here

Comment: Neither. Polymorphism is the ability to reference a child class using a parent class pointer, and inheritance is the ability of deriving a class from a parent class. The correct term would be overriding.